# How to stop windows from shutting down?

Tags: windows-7, windows

My HP touchsmart520 PC is shutting the windows down after 2 minutes if I am just looking and goes to the log in window! What should I do?

Comment: You say it shuts down but goes to the log on window. Is that a shut down, reboot, or log off?

Comment: +1, I must admit I thought it was rebooting and didn't consider it could be only logging off!

Comment: After 2 minutes of looking at what? Are you implying not touching any thing, or are you watching a video? Much more detail is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your machine is shutting down, there could be many reasons.

Over heating. This will normally be shown in event viewer so check the logs to see if anything sheds any light.

Scheduled tasks - Go through the tasks and see if anything looks suspicious

MSCONFIG - Type in MSCONFIG into the search box and navigate to the start up tab. There could be something running in here which is causing the issue.

Virus or similar malicious code - Get a good quality AV and a Malware scanner and sweep the computer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential reasons might be a corrupt or non-adjacent battery for the BIOS. However, you should give more symptoms, it is hard to tell what it is exactly.